# How many Spark Executor Pods you run per Kubernetes Node

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

Spark needs lots of resources to does its job. Kubernetes is great environment for resource management. How many Spark PODs do you run per node to have the best resource utilization?

Trying to run Spark Cluster on Kubernetes Cluster.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on many factors. We need to know how much resources do you have and how much is being consumed by the pods. To do so you need to [setup a Metrics-server](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server).

[Metrics Server](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/resource-metrics-pipeline/) is a cluster-wide aggregator of resource usage data.

Next step is to setup HPA.

The Horizontal Pod Autoscaler automatically scales the number of pods in a replication controller, deployment or replica set based on observed CPU utilization or other custom metrics. HPA normally fetches metrics from a series of aggregated APIs:

- metrics.k8s.io
- custom.metrics.k8s.io
- external.metrics.k8s.io

How to make it work?

HPA is being supported by kubectl by default:

- `kubectl create` - creates a new autoscaler
- `kubectl get hpa` - lists your autoscalers
- `kubectl describe hpa` - gets a detailed description of autoscalers
- `kubectl delete` - deletes an autoscaler

Example:
`kubectl autoscale rs foo --min=2 --max=5 --cpu-percent=80` creates an autoscaler for replication set foo, with target CPU utilization set to 80% and the number of replicas between 2 and 5. You can and should adjust all values to your needs.

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#autoscale) is a detailed documentation of how to use kubectl autoscale command.

Please let me know if you find that useful.

Comment: Thanks Mark. My background is all k8s (and no Spark) so I am familiar with what you've mentioned here. The challenge is this: If you size your nodes and executors the same (one pod per node) you will have a delay in autoscaling the cluster (10-15min on AWS for creating and setting up new node).   If you make pods smaller than nodes and use HPA then you have a problem of running multiple instances of executors on the same node and effecting each other's performance as result (in our case different customers)

Comment: You can go multiple pods per multiple nodes and use CA and HPA/VPA at the same time until you feel happy with your configuration. Don't narrow your options to just the two you mentioned above. Cluster scaling is very adjustable topic which can and should be looked at from different angles. Consider your resources and consider the time needed in order to scale up or down. Understanding how different autoscalers work together will help you configure your cluster. I know that this isn't the exact straight answer you need but maybe it will show you the bigger picture.